# Как активировать строку поиска программно?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Мне нужно, чтобы после загрузки карты появлялась строка поиска https://skr.sh/s9Gx0kqP5nE => https://skr.sh/s9GViX5tnzh
Из документации нашёл лишь показать результаты, например:

```
let searchControl = Map.map.controls.get('searchControl');

searchControl.search('Введите адрес').then(res => {
    searchControl.showResult(0);
});
```

Но и в таком случае строка поиска остаётся скрытой и активируется только после нажатия на лупу https://skr.sh/s9GzljtCgpy

Answer (score 2):

Элемент управления «Поиск по карте» реализуется классом [control.SearchControl](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/control.SearchControl.html). Добавить элемент на карту можно двумя способами:

При создании карты:

```
var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.75, 37.57],
    zoom: 9,
    controls: ['searchControl']
}, {
    // Будет производиться поиск по топонимам и организациям.
    searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
});
```

Добавив на существующую карту:

```
var searchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
    options: {
    // Будет производиться поиск по топонимам и организациям.
    provider: 'yandex#search'
   }
});
myMap.controls.add(searchControl);
```

Для поиска по карте доступно два провайдера данных:

- yandex#map — поиск только по топонимам. Позволяет настроить отображение результатов.
- yandex#search — поиск по топонимам и организациям.

Провайдер поиска задается с помощью опции provider при создании поисковой строки:

```
var searchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
    options: {
        provider: 'yandex#map'
    }
});
```

Программно выполнить поиск какого-нибудь объекта можно с помощью функции [search()](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/control.SearchControl.html#method_detail__search):
`searchControl.search('Дворцовая площадь, 2');`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отображение результата на карте (`showResult`):

```
// Пример всегда показывает первый результат,
// вне зависимости от количества найденных
// объектов на карте.
var searchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
   options: {
       noSelect: true
   }
});

searchControl.events.add('load', function (event) {
    // Проверяет, что это событие не "дозагрузка" результатов и
    // по запросу найден хотя бы один результат.
    if (!event.get('skip') && searchControl.getResultsCount()) {
        searchControl.showResult(0);
    }
});
```

UPD:

```
function init() {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.74, 37.58],
        zoom: 13,
        controls: []
    });
    
    // Создадим экземпляр элемента управления «поиск по карте»
    // с установленной опцией провайдера данных для поиска по организациям.
    var searchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
        options: {
            provider: 'yandex#search'
        }
    });
    
    myMap.controls.add(searchControl);
    
    // Программно выполним поиск определённых кафе в текущей
    // прямоугольной области карты.
    searchControl.search('Шоколадница');
}

ymaps.ready(init);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Песочница](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/search_control_ppo)

[Источник](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/geocoding/searchControl.html)

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы отобразилась эта панель https://skr.sh/s9HPPUiabpt, то есть как бы на лупу кликнуть программно надо https://skr.sh/s9HVhALSOLX.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать свой пример на карте таких размеров, где изначально вместо строки поиска - иконка лупы. Может так будет понятнее.

Comment: Указанный вами способ работает только при searchControl.state.set('size', 'large');
Я же хочу знать, как активировать панель поиска программно для значений medium и small.